# Why is C++ lambda implemented with functor instead of function pointer?

Tags: c++, lambda

I found out that lambdas in both MSVC and GCC are functors implementing an `operator()`. What is the reason they prefer functor to function pointers?

Comment: Because the standard says so? They need space for captures, too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that a lambda function in C++ can have an additional state (captured variables aka context) which has to be passed around for each instance (they can differ for each instance of the handle to the same lambda function).

A function cannot have a state coupled to the handle you pass around. If you would add such a state to a function pointer you end up writing a wrapper which needs to be callable using the parenthesis syntax (`operator()`) which happens to be what a functor is.

A notable fact is that a lambda *without* a capture can be converted to a function pointer. This is only possible because it does *not* require such additional space.

Comment: I did read a proposal to add *capturing* lambda conversion to function pointer whose duration of validity is the same as the closure instance.  This is actually possible in most architectures by writing data that contains machine language instructions and a pointer to the lambda, then marking it as executable, then returning a pointer to that function you just created at run time.  I have no idea what the state of that proposal is.

Comment: @Yakk Or simply use a global variable? ;) (Indeed, that was the reason why I added the last part of the first paragraph in the edit of my answer.)

Comment: multiple instances of the lambda with different captured state then fail to work.  Basically, on many platforms, we can generate function pointers with state stored in the code they point to, and there are a myriad of legacy APIs that do not provide the `void*, void(*func)(void*)` stateful callback pair.

Comment: @Yakk Oh I didn't fully understand what you mean. Now I got it. But sounds like a hack to me... Also, there are some (important) architectures which don't allow this afaik (iOS?) but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Functions don't have state, so they wouldn't be able to implement the functionality required by lambdas.

Moreover, you are guaranteed that lambdas have a unique type, which you can't really do with functions alone.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the already mentioned ability to capture, performance is also a reason. In general a function pointer can not be inlined. A functor can be. This is why std::sort is faster than qsort. As mentioned a lambda without captures can be turned into a function pointer, but this is mostly to interact with old c api's. i.e. so you can pass a lambda to an old win32 api function. In general for a simple lambda, the compiler would prefer to inline it instead.